# in R dplyr package, a question about function rename_with()

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

There is data.frame `ori_df`, i want to change the column names using `rename_with()`,but failed.
Anyone can help on this ?Thanks!

```
 library(tidyverse)
    ori_df <- data.frame(my_item=c('a','b','c'),
                         'y2021'=c(1,4,5),
                         'y2022'=c(9,8,7))
#blow code show error message : Error: Can't convert a character vector to function
ori_df_final <- ori_df %>% rename_with(.,c('item','2021','2022'))
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `rename_with`? You probably should remove the `., `, but I would recommend doing `names(ori_df) <- c('item', '2021', '2022')` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `rename_with`, you need to provide a function. In this case, we can just pass a character vector of the new names to replace all column names. If you have a larger dataframe and only want change a few names, then you can select those as normal with `dplyr` (e.g., `c(my_item, y2021, y2022)` instead of `everything()`).

```
library(dplyr)

ori_df %>% 
   rename_with(~ c('item','2021','2022'), everything())

#  item 2021 2022
#1    a    1    9
#2    b    4    8
#3    c    5    7
```

If you are replacing all columns, then `everything()` is the default for the `.cols` argument, so you can just write:

```
ori_df %>% 
    rename_with(~c('item','2021','2022'))
```